# For Loop is executing longer than asked

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a problem in the for loop in the code below. It should loop until it reaches the (`lastrow - 6`) value. In testing this code myself in debug mode, it works everytime and properly exits, however when in use by the end user the for loop seems to run 1-3 more loops than it should before it exits the loop. This causes problems when looking at the data because the dates are not lining up with the pasted data.

```
Sub ClearDPR()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim Found As Range
    Dim copydate As Long
    Dim CopyShift As String
    Dim CopyCRO As String
    Dim BlankCells As Long
    Dim LastRowArchive As Long
    Dim Answer As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim startrow As Integer

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With


    ' PRINT REMINDER AND DPR CLEAR CONFIRMATION
    Answer = MsgBox("Have you printed the DPR?", vbYesNo, "Clear DPR")
    If Answer = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    Else                                         'COPY PASTE ACTIVITY SHEET ITEMS TO ARCHIVE
        'IF COLUMN O IS COMPLETE, THEN CHECKS PRIOR CELLS FILLED BEFORE CONSIDERING ROW & COLUMN AS TARGET CELL (ELSE MSGBOX)
        lastrow = wsActSht.Range("A7").End(xlDown).Row
        BlankCells = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(wsActSht.Range("A7:R" & lastrow))

        If BlankCells <> 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Please fill the " & BlankCells & " blank cell(s) on DPR.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If BlankCells = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Entry accepted", vbInformation, "Accepted"

            If wsActSht.FilterMode = True Then
                wsActSht.ShowAllData
            End If


            'THEN COPY PASTE A:Q FROM ACTIVITY SHEET TO ARCHIVE STARTING WITH COLUMN D
            LastRowArchive = wsArch.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            If SheetProtected(wsArch) Then
                wsArch.Unprotect "password"      'Unprotect Archive
            End If

            If wsArch.FilterMode = True Then
                wsArch.ShowAllData
            End If


            wsActSht.Range("A7:B" & lastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Archive").Range("D" & LastRowArchive)
            wsActSht.Range("D7:R" & lastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Archive").Range("F" & LastRowArchive)
            wsArch.Activate

            ' COPIES AND PASTES B5,D5,F5 FROM ACTIVITY SHEET TO SYNC WITH ROW PASTED ABOVE
            For r = 1 To lastrow - 6
                copydate = wsActSht.Range("B5").Value - 1
                CopyShift = wsActSht.Range("E5").Value & " &" & Chr(10) & wsActSht.Range("I5").Value
                CopyCRO = wsActSht.Range("G5").Value & " &" & Chr(10) & wsActSht.Range("K5").Value
                wsArch.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" 'short date format of date before paste to archive
                wsArch.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = copydate
                wsArch.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 20).Value = Format(Now(), "m/dd/yyyy h:mmAM/PM")
                wsArch.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = CopyShift
                wsArch.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = CopyCRO
                wsArch.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.AutoFit 'size row to show all contents of COLUMN C
            Next r

            wsArch.Protect "password", , , , , , , , , , , , , True, True 'Protect Archive

            'REFRESH DPR FOR NEXT 24 HOUR USE
            wsActSht.Activate
            Range("I7:J" & lastrow).Select
            Selection.ClearContents              'CLEAR DAY AND NIGHT OPERATORS
            Range("N7:O" & lastrow).Select
            Selection.ClearContents              'CLEAR LBS RAN SPACE FOR BOTH SHIFTS

            startrow = 7
            For i = startrow To lastrow          'INDEXES ROWS AND REMOVE ROWS MARKED YES IN COLUMN Q (ROWS WHICH HAVE BEEN INDICATED THAT THE LOT IS COMPLETE)
                If Range("R" & i).Value = "YES" Or Range("R" & i).Value = "Yes" Or Range("R" & i).Value = "yes" Then
                    Range("R" & i).Select
                    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
                    i = i - 1
                End If
            Next i

            'CLEAR SHIFT AND CRO FOR DAYS AND NIGHTS

            With wsActSht
                .Range("E5").Value = "Click Here"
                .Range("I5").Value = "Click Here"
                .Range("G5").Value = ""
                .Range("K5").Value = ""
            End With

            MsgBox ("DPR Cleared to completion")

            'SAVE DOCUMENT
            LotFolder.Save

        End If
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Such problems usually arise from unqualified ranges. Most of your code is fine but towards the end you are missing some sheet references - add those and see if the problem disappears.

Comment: Could you be more specific about which sheet references i am missing?

Comment: I may have jumped the gun as I missed the `wsActSht.Activate` line.This means all the subsequent range references will refer to this sheet. See @Brandon Barney's answer for a much fuller explanation of the problems caused by this.

Comment: Note that you toggle application settings off at the beginning, but they only get turned back on if `MsgBox = vbYes`. You might want to look into that.

Comment: @chillin , great suggestion...didn't even see this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few areas where you will want to check your code.

First, `wsActSht` isn't defined within the scope of your subroutine. If `wsActSheet` is a `Public` (also known as `Global`) variable, then this is a code smell. Additionally, that name looks awfully like `ActiveSheet`. This isn't CodeReview, so i'll spare the rant, but, in short, use descriptive names.

Next, I am not quite sure this is the line you are looking for:

```
lastrow = wsActSht.Range("A7").End(xlDown).Row
```

This will find the first interruption within your rows, not the last row with data in it. Generally, the pattern is:

```
lastrow = wsActSht.Range("A7").End(xlUp).Row
```

Next, you have a few instances of this pattern:

```
LastRowArchive = wsArch.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

Notice that `Rows.Count` means `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` which is not the same as `wsActSht.Rows.Count` (see how that might bite you in the butt?). Your `wsActSht` holds reference to the `Worksheet` that was `Active` when it was `Set`, not the currently `ActiveSheet`.

Along these lines, watch out for this as well:

```
... Destination:=Sheets("Archive").Range("D" & LastRowArchive)
```

Again, `Sheets` here refers to `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets` and not `ThisWorkbook.Sheets`. You're bound to get a `Subscript Out of Range` error here.

Here's another one:

```
wsActSht.Activate
Range("I7:J" & lastrow).Select
Selection.ClearContents              'CLEAR DAY AND NIGHT OPERATORS
Range("N7:O" & lastrow).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

Guess what happens if, between the `Activate` statement and the rest of it, another worksheet becomes active? All of a sudden you are now potentially deleting all of the data on that sheet, and there is no way of getting it back.

So, how do you remedy all of this?

First, make sure **everything** is qualified. Create your variables with *descriptive names* such as `DPR`, or `SheetToClear` so that you know what you are working on, and when you are working on it. This includes `Workbook` variables. I prefer `ThisWorkbook` but that assumes your code is working on the `Workbook` that is running it. If this isn't the case, you can create a variable for this purpose.

Once you have done this, you need to train yourself to look for anything at a lower level that doesn't have something in front of it. So:

```
Rows.Count
Range("A1").Value
Sheets("SuperImportantData")
```

All become code smells because they should be:

```
SomeImportantSheet.Rows.Count
SomeImportantSheet.Range("A1").Value
SomeImportantWorkbook.Sheets("SomeImportantData")
```

By enforcing this practice, you will save yourself many headaches.

Finally, **do not use `.Activate`**. No if's, and's or but's about it. Unless you are quite literally using `Activate` to return the view back to where the user started, there is no good reason to use `Activate`. Use variables instead.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. `wsActSht`, `wsArch` are all worksheet names defined in the sheet properties in the (Name) field. Allows me to shorten code from `Sheets("Activity Sheet")` to `wsActSht`. Agree that it does sound similar to active sheet. Also, the `lastrow = wsActSht.Range("A7").End(xlDown).Row` is finding the first interuption below `A7` as `A1-A6` are blank header rows. will look into each of your suggestions below. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

When you set `lastrow`, the value may vary depending on the data in that column.

For example, if there are entries from A8-A10 lastrow will be 10. If A9 is blank, lastrow will be 8.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: You may want to explain a bit further what you mean. I believe you are referring more to the `End(xlDown)` causing the lastrow to be 8, but other users might not be able to follow your train of thought.

Comment: @BrandonBarney Thank you for the advice. I wanted to leave a comment along these lines, but I don't have the rep for that yet

Comment: Its not a problem. Your first few answers on SO you're bound to learn what works and what doesn't. Just keep in mind that, more often than not, our answers help future programmers who are stuck with a similar question, so being as clear as we can in our answers now will not only help the OP, but it will help future askers as well.